# how to get only values from json column as comma seprated

Tags: python, pandas

I am updating the my question .
I have a dataframe and a json formatted column rawrecord

```
filedate    code    errorID rawrecord                                                                                                                       errortype
20230811    8003    100     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"30811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"111111111111",flag:False} BBBB
20230811    8003    101     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"20811-195555-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"111111111112",flag:False} BBBB
20230811    8003    102     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"50811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"411111111111",flag:False} BBBB
20230811    8003    103     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"60811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"511111111111",flag:False} BBBB
20230811    8003    104     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"40811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"611111111111",flag:False} BBBB
20230811    8003    105     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"80811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"811111111111",flag:False} BBBB
20230811    8003    106     {"Action":"NEW","ID":"70811-195552-952","EventType":"MMMM","Date":"20230811T000000.000000","orderID":"911111111111",flag:False} AAAA
```

I would like to extract all the values from the column rawrecord  and comma seprate them.

result:

```
filedate    code    errorID rawrecord                                                                                                                       errortype
20230811    8003    100     NEW,30811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.000000,111111111111,False                                                             BBBB
20230811    8003    101     NEW,20811-195555-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.000000,111111111112,False                                                             BBBB
20230811    8003    102     NEW,50811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.000000,411111111111,False                                                             BBBB
20230811    8003    103     NEW,60811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.000000,511111111111,False                                                             BBBB
20230811    8003    104     NEW,40811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.000000,611111111111,False                                                             BBBB
20230811    8003    105     NEW,80811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.000000,811111111111,False                                                             BBBB
20230811    8003    106     NEW,70811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.000000,911111111111,False                                                             AAAA
```

How can i get only values seperated by comma for raw record column?

[image]

Comment: You want one result returned for each row in your dataframe right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df['data'] = pd.json_normalize(df['json']).agg(','.join, axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
                                                json                                               data
0  {'color': 'Red', 'wavelength': '620 to 750 nm'...  Red,620 to 750 nm,(255,0,0),(0.00, 1.00, 1.00,...
```

You can also use [`pd.Dataframe.from_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['json']).agg(','.join, axis=1).rename('data')
out = pd.concat([df, data], axis=1)
```

I appears you have not a valid python or json data string. You have to extract the values manually with a regex:

```
>>> df.rawrecord.str.replace('"', '').str.findall(':([^,}]+)').str.join(',')
0    NEW,30811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.0000...
1    NEW,20811-195555-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.0000...
2    NEW,50811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.0000...
3    NEW,60811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.0000...
4    NEW,40811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.0000...
5    NEW,80811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.0000...
6    NEW,70811-195552-952,MMMM,20230811T000000.0000...
Name: rawrecord, dtype: object
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me.. i have updated my question. can you please let me know if it makes sense?

Comment: @unicorn. Can you check the key `flag`. If it's a JSON string, it should be enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: my data looks exactly like what I have posted here. key is in double quotes.

Comment: But `Flag` is not and `False` should be `false` in JSON.

Comment: Please provide the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`.

Comment: i uploaded an image for print(df.head().to_dict())

Comment: It's not JSON or Python data structure!!!

Comment: i am new to python and json.. sorry about that. This is how we receive the data and wanted to flatten it out.

Comment: Does it work: `df.rawrecord.str.replace('"', '').str.findall(':([^,}]+)').str.join(',')`?

Comment: it did. thank you so so much. can you please explain what happened by replacing the quotes?

Comment: You already have a string so inner (double) quotes are useless so I remove it and extract only the values (after : and before , or }). I updated my answer.